# Using Google Cloud service account is VSTS build

Tags: azure-pipelines, google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I'm running my automated builds on VSTS and part of the build is running integration tests against GCP.

I've set up a service account on GCP which grants the minimum permissions required to run the tests and have downloaded the JSON key.

I'm struggling with how to use that key within the VSTS build process .I can add the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable which points to the file easily enough but I'm not sure where to keep the JSON key so it's still secure or if I'm missing another approach which might work?

I'm pretty new to GCP so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the secure information in the [secret variable(s)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/variables?tabs=batch#secret-variables), then replace the value to the JSON file through [Replace Token task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens) (Install it to your VSTS) before calling service, at the end of build, you can remove the secure information from JSON file or delete it directly. (If you are using Hosted agent, the source files will be cleared automatically)

1. Edit build definition
2. Select Variables tab
3. Click Add button to add new variable (e.g. Name: `key1`; Value: [secure info]), click lock icon to change variable type to secret
4. Edit the JSON file to replace the secure info to the token (e.g. `#{key1}#`, key1 is the variable name)
5. Add Replace Tokens task and specify Target files
6. Other tasks to call service
7. Add Delete Files task to delete JSON file or other way to clear secure information.